# Deploy Angular.js App in Salesforce (SFDC)

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

Deploy angular.js app in Salesforce (SFDC).
 I have tried using  https://developer.salesforce.com/en/mobile/getting-started/html5/#angularjs

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Visualforce?

Comment: yes , Please help me on this. But I dont have mobile app, normal web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a draft article and sample app that combines AngularJS and Bootstrap in Visualforce: https://github.com/jamesward/visualforce-angular-bootstrap/blob/master/ARTICLE.md

Comment: any tool for developing Visualforce and Angular.js then deploy on Salesforce.

Comment: That project is an example of that.